# Scraping How to isolate multiple element in same code source on website

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
headers={'User-Agent': 'Chrome/106.0.0.0'}
page = "https://www.transfermarkt.com/premier-league/einnahmenausgaben/wettbewerb/GB1/ids/a/sa//saison_id/2010/saison_id_bis/2010/nat/0/pos//w_s//intern/0"
pageTree = requests.get(page, headers=headers)
pageSoup = BeautifulSoup(pageTree.content, 'html.parser')
ClubList = []
ExpenditureList = []
ArrivalsList = []
IncomeList = []
DeparturesList = []
BalanceList = []
Club = pageSoup.find_all("td", {"class": "hauptlink no-border-links"})
Expenditure = pageSoup.find_all("td", {"class": "rechts hauptlink redtext"})
Arrivals = pageSoup.find_all("td", {"class": "zentriert"})
Income = pageSoup.find_all("td", {"class": "rechts hauptlink greentext"})
Departures = pageSoup.find_all("td", {"class": "zentriert"})
Balance = pageSoup.find_all("td", {"class": "rechts hauptlink"})for i in range(0,20):
    ClubList.append(Club[i].text)
    ExpenditureList.append(Expenditure[i].text)
    ArrivalsList.append(Arrivals[i].text)
    IncomeList.append(Income[i].text)
    DeparturesList.append(Departures[i].text)
    BalanceList.append(Balance[i].text)
    
df = pd.DataFrame({"Club":ClubList,"Expenditure":ExpenditureList,"Arrivals":ArrivalsList,"Income":IncomeList,"Departures":DeparturesList,"Balance":BalanceList})

df.head(20)
```

[i want to scrape Arrivals and Departures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mv7oD.png)
[so i miss something to search the right information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7K5g.png)

Hi everyone
i have a problem in the same code source, i want to seperate information in the same code source but i did'nt know how i can do that
thanks in advance for you help

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `pd.read_html`:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.transfermarkt.com/premier-league/einnahmenausgaben/wettbewerb/GB1/ids/a/sa//saison_id/2010/saison_id_bis/2010/nat/0/pos//w_s//intern/0"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:105.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/105.0"
}


df = pd.read_html(requests.get(url, headers=headers).text)[1]
df = df.drop(columns=["club", "#", "Balance"])
df.columns = [
    "club",
    "Expenditure",
    "Arrivals",
    "Income",
    "Departures",
    "Balance",
]
print(df.to_markdown(index=False))
```

Prints:

| club | Expenditure | Arrivals | Income | Departures | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Manchester City | €183.61m | 33 | €40.15m | 26 | €-143.46m |
| Chelsea FC | €121.50m | 19 | €16.50m | 21 | €-105.00m |
| Liverpool FC | €97.73m | 21 | €101.50m | 24 | €3.78m |
| Aston Villa | €37.40m | 20 | €28.40m | 20 | €-9.00m |
| Manchester United | €29.30m | 16 | €16.97m | 18 | €-12.34m |
| Sunderland AFC | €29.10m | 29 | €41.78m | 29 | €12.68m |
| Tottenham Hotspur | €26.60m | 39 | €2.94m | 33 | €-23.67m |
| Birmingham City | €25.60m | 24 | €175Th. | 21 | €-25.43m |
| Arsenal FC | €23.00m | 18 | €8.10m | 22 | €-14.90m |
| Stoke City | €21.10m | 24 | €6.78m | 23 | €-14.33m |
| Wolverhampton Wanderers | €20.22m | 28 | €6.44m | 25 | €-13.78m |
| West Ham United | €18.03m | 18 | €4.95m | 19 | €-13.08m |
| Newcastle United | €13.98m | 18 | €41.75m | 16 | €27.77m |
| West Bromwich Albion | €13.83m | 28 | €850Th. | 25 | €-12.98m |
| Wigan Athletic | €11.40m | 23 | €3.40m | 21 | €-8.00m |
| Fulham FC | €11.05m | 16 | €12.81m | 22 | €1.76m |
| Blackpool FC | €5.73m | 27 | €700Th. | 23 | €-5.03m |
| Bolton Wanderers | €5.40m | 17 | €1.40m | 19 | €-4.00m |
| Blackburn Rovers | €5.05m | 29 | €275Th. | 29 | €-4.78m |
| Everton FC | €1.70m | 12 | €6.60m | 14 | €4.90m |

Comment: This is work perfectly 
great job Andrej